# Extension of smooth structure on three dimensional topological manifolds

Tags: differential-topology, 3-manifolds, smooth-structures

Let $M$ be a three dimensional compact topological manifold and $U$ an open set in $M$ homeomorphic to some smooth $C^k$ manifold $U'$, $1 \leq k \leq \omega$. Can we extend the smooth structure on $U$ given by this identification to the whole of $M$? In other words, is there a $C^k$ manifold $M'$ homeomorphic to $M$ such that $U'$ is diffeomorphic to an open subset of $M'$?

The question of course can be asked in all dimensions but I am specifically interested in the three dimensional case.

Comment: In higher dimensions there are counterexamples: there are topological $n$-manifolds not admitting smooth structures, and we can choose $U$ to be a ball. (Note that if there's a $C^k$ atlas for some $k > 1$, there's automatically a $C^\infty$ one.)

Comment: There is an obstruction theory dealing with such matters, see "Obstructions to the Smoothing of Piecewise-Differentiable Homeomorphisms" by Munkres, but I think it requires that $U$ sits nicely in $M$.